# Custom form that stores data in mysql database

Tags: php, database, mysql, forms

Im currently building a website that allows a user to rent a boat rack but they need to be in the town in order to rent. I want to know how to create a form that allows the user to input their address which checks the address to a MySQL database and allows the user to submit the form if they are in town. I'm only 15 and have about 2 years worth of coding language under my belt and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome.  Unfortunately, this particular site is specific to WordPress, and so this needs to be a WP question.  WP does have a built in db class that would allow you to handle MySQL queries, but your question needs to have some kind of a structure to it that shows what you're trying and where you are stuck.  (You may actually have more than one question in there - creating/displaying the form, and form data validation.)

Comment: Ill start off with how do you create a form on WordPress that submits the answer to the question to a MySQL database so that it can be stored

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I want to save certain information from a form into MySQL database through wordpress